# Вывод файла в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я не могу получить нормальный вывод файла в python

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from pathlib import Path
import re


print("pathdir format: '/home/asmnv/Desktop/'")
pathdir = str(input("Enter your pathdir: "))

print("File has extension? Y or N: ")
q1 = str(input())
print(q1)

if q1 == "Y" or "yes": 
    print("Enter your file extension: ")
    file_extension = str(input())
    fe = str("*."+file_extension)

elif q1 == "N" or "no":
    print("enter your extension: ")
    fe = str(input())
else:
    print("Goodbye!")
    quit()

for txt_path in [_ for _ in Path(pathdir).rglob(fe) if _.is_file()]:
    print(txt_path.absolute())
    file = open(txt_path.absolute(),"r").read()
    

    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
    pdf.cell(200, 15, txt=file, ln=1, align="C")
    
    
    print(" ")
    print("Your footer:")
    print("________________________________________")
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print(file)
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print("________________________________________")

    print("Name for save file: ")
    file_name = str(input())+".pdf"
    
    pdf.output(file_name)
    print("File: "+file_name+"be saved in Desktop!")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да, извините. Есть код - его задача преобразовывать любое расширение файла - в pdf. Он открывает файл - преобразовывает - но вывод получается в одну строку. Я не доволен этим - нужно чтобы отрабатывал перенос .

Comment: плюс я столкнулся с тем, что в моём коде не работают условные операторы - посмотрите  на q1 - мы видим - что там существует 2 условия - из которых следует либо отрицание - либо продолжение работы ПО. К сожалению они не работают

Comment: Они работают. Просто у вас неверное представление об их работе.

Answer (score 1):

это выражение:

```
q1 == "N" or "no"
```

вернет `True` если `q1 = 'N'` и `'no'` если, например, `q1 = 'Y'`

вероятно вам нужно:

```
q1 in ['N', 'no']
```

Comment: всё равно он благополучно возвращает результат из Y

Comment: а нет - спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решение заключается в том, чтобы использовать метод multi_cell в FPDF